# Asp.NET MVC 4 deployment issues related to LocalDb and SQLExpress

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to deploy a Asp.NET MVC 4 app to a third-party host, and encountered some problems while following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis).

1. The tutorial created 2 `New SQL Server Database`, and set the `Remote connection string` of `DefaultConnection` to one SQLExpress database and that of `SchoolContext` to another. However, I want to have only one database, so I only created one `New SQL Server Database`, and used the same connection string for `DefaultConnection` AND `MyAppContext`. Would this cause problem?

Right now my app won't publish with the following error. not sure if it stems from this. `MyAppUsr` comes from a Grant script, `Grant.sql`, that I developed from this tutorial.

```
Error   3   Web deployment task failed. (An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "8" and "11". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
"CREATE USER [MyAppUsr] "
 The login already has an account under a different user name. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.)        0   0   MvcCP
```

2. `MyAppContext` uses LocalDb instead of SQLExpress. The deployment in the tutorial uses SQLExpress. Can I just create a new SQLExpress database and have `MyAppContext` (LocalDb) "points to" the SQLExpress database?

Answer (score 0):

You must have run the script at least once prior, correct?  Because what it is saying is that the user [MyAppUsr] already exists.  You will need to drop the user first, then rerun it.  ie:

```
DROP USER [MyAppUsr]
```

You can embed that into your script, better yet, put a conditional check if exists...